# Can a real function be discontinuous relative to any subset or its complement?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in \{g : g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}.$ Is it possible for any measurable subset $A$, $f$ is discontinuous in either the subspace topology of $A$ or that of $A^c$?

Lusin's theorem implies $f$ cannot be measurable if it exists. Yet none of the books I've read talks much about nonmeasurable functions.

Answer (score 0):

The measurable solutions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ of Cauchy's functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ are linear, i.e., of the form $x\mapsto c x$ with constant $c$. But there are many other solutions: If $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals, any $\mathbb{Q}$-linear function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ solves the functional equation. And $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear iff there is some $c$ such that $f(b)=cb$ for all $b\in B$. So choosing $b_1,b_2\in B$ and $f$ such that $f(b_1)=b_1, f(b_2)=2b_2$ (and $f(b)$ arbitrary for $b\not=b_1,b_2$) gives non measurable functions.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about the existence of non-measurable functions.

Comment: These functions are nowhere continuous!

Comment: Sure, there is no point where it's continuous as a function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$. But that still doesn't answer the question, because we're not interested in whether it's continuous as a function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$. We are interested in its restriction to measurable subsets of $\Bbb R$ and whether it's continuous there. For instance, any such function is continuous on the rationals.